# Error inflating class fragments

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

This app is about a cricket database and live scores of a cricket League.I Started getting weird errors when i introduced fragments to my code.Now there is a problem with itself fragment .There are errors in inflating the fragment  .My fragment Consist of a RecyclerView in which when i select a player its get displayed in a activity. I am not able to solve this and i am stuck .I could really use some help here. Thank you in advance.

Admin_ScoreCard.java

```
public void BatBowl(String Calling,String Who)
   {
    getData(Calling);
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction;
    FragmentManager fragmentManager;
    Frag_ScoreCard Frag_ScoreCard;
    fragmentManager=getSupportFragmentManager();
    fragmentTransaction=fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    Frag_ScoreCard=new Frag_ScoreCard();
    Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
    bundle.putStringArrayList("Data",data);
    bundle.putString("Who",Who);
    Frag_ScoreCard.setArguments(bundle);
    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.ScoreCard,Frag_ScoreCard);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```

Frag_ScoreCard
        package com.zodiac.sanghvi.jplreborn;

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import java.util.ArrayList;



public class Frag_ScoreCard extends Fragment implements com.zodiac.sanghvi.jplreborn.Player_Adapter.Player_Comm
    {
RecyclerView Player_Rv;
Player_Adapter Player_Adapter;
ArrayList<String> data;
String current;
Bundle getData;
Frag_Comm frag_Comm;
Context context;

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    this.context=context;
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    View v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_frag_admin_scorecard,container,false);

    getData=getArguments();
    if(getData!=null)
        data=getData.getStringArrayList("Data");
    Player_Rv= (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.Player_Rv);
    Player_Adapter=new Player_Adapter(context,data);
    Player_Rv.setAdapter(Player_Adapter);
    Player_Rv.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
    Player_Adapter.setItemClicked(this);
    return v;
}

@Override
public void ItemClicked(int position)
{
    current=data.get(position);
    frag_Comm.ItemUsed(current,getData.getString("Who"),"Clicked");
    getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(this).commit();
}

@Override
public void ItemLongClicked(int position)
{
    current=data.get(position);
    frag_Comm.ItemUsed(current,getData.getString("Who"),"LongClicked");
    getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(this).commit();
}

interface Frag_Comm
{
    void ItemUsed(String current,String BatBowl,String Clicked);
}
}
```

Admin_ScoreCard.xml- It has varoius other stuff but only listed the fragment part

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/List"
    android:name="com.zodiac.sanghvi.jplreborn.Frag_ScoreCard"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    tools:layout="@layout/layout_frag_admin_scorecard" />
```

Frag_ScoreCard.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    android:padding="16dp">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/Player_Rv">
    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Error

```
         E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                        Process: com.zodiac.sanghvi.jplreborn, PID: 1919
                                                                        java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.zodiac.sanghvi.jplreborn/com.zodiac.sanghvi.jplreborn.Admin_ScoreCard}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #220: Binary XML file line #220: Error inflating class fragment
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2432)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2492)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:156)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1352)
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5469)
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                                         Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #220: Binary XML file line #220: Error inflating class fragment
                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
                                                                            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:292)
                                                                            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
                                                                            at com.zodiac.sanghvi.jplreborn.Admin_ScoreCard.onCreate(Admin_ScoreCard.java:60)
                                                                            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6555)
                                                                            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2385)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2492) 
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:156) 
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1352) 
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5469) 
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
                                                                         Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #220: Error inflating class fragment
                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:782)
                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835)
                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
                                                                            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:292) 
                                                                            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
                                                                            at com.zodiac.sanghvi.jplreborn.Admin_ScoreCard.onCreate(Admin_ScoreCard.java:60) 
                                                                            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6555) 
                                                                            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108) 
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2385) 
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2492) 
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:156) 
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1352) 
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5469) 
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
                                                                         Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.util.ArrayList android.os.Bundle.getStringArrayList(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
                                                                            at com.zodiac.sanghvi.jplreborn.Frag_ScoreCard.onCreateView(Frag_ScoreCard.java:42)
                                                                            at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2192)
                                                                            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1255)
                                                                            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1472)
                                                                            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1691)
                                                                            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:3440)
                                                                            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:120)
                                                                            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.dispatchFragmentsOnCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:378)
                                                                            at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.onCreateView(BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.java:33)
                                                                            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:79)
                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:754)
                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704) 
                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835) 
                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515) 
                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
                                                                            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:292) 
                                                                            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
                                                                            at com.zodiac.sanghvi.jplreborn.Admin_ScoreCard.onCreate(Admin_ScoreCard.java:60) 
                                                                            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6555) 
                                                                            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108) 
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2385) 
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2492) 
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:156) 
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1352) 
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5469) 
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: In your error stack trace there is this: `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.util.ArrayList android.os.Bundle.getStringArrayList(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference`. Try to look into this issue instead

Comment: i get that error whn i use the statement if(getData!=null) while Calling the Arraylist from the bundle.How do i solve that.